# How do I manually set up libraries for a python cgi script?

Tags: python, devops, libraries, setup-deployment

I'm running in a shared hosting environment where I don't have admin. I want to run a Python script that uses modules from mpmath and another library, which have not been installed.

I've placed the libraries under `$myroot/lib/mpmath1.1/math` and included the following in my `.htaccess file`:

```
SetEnv PYTHONPATH $myroot/lib/mpmath1.1/mpmath:$myroot/lib/lib2
```

(myroot is explicit)

But this isn't working. Is there a way for me to do this? I'm running on ipage.

Comment: We don't know which web server you are using or how or where `$myroot` is defined. Quickly googling "ipage" reveals nothing even vaguely relevant. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify this?

Comment: You can modify `sys.path` at the beginning of your script, or put in a wrapper script which adds this configuration, then dispatches your regular script, perhaps as a shell script. Vaguely also look into virtual environments, though this isn't really useful if you already installed these libraries and you only want to run a single application.